# What kind of question do you upvote on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I haven't been on this site for long, and I'm only checking web-developing related questions, but since I've been here, on those questions I barely see any upvotes at all. **Mostly downvotes, or no votes at all.**

I see that many of the questions are asked by new users who ask terrible questions often, and that's why they get downvotes, but I see **many** good questions, which show actual effort, well-organized text, codes, images, etc., and sometimes they still get downvotes, or no votes at all.

So here's the actual question:

What kind of question do you consider as a good one, which actually deserves an upvote from you?

Comment: **This will come under primarily opinion-based / too broad** - '*Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.*' - **However, I personally up-vote those questions that include relevant information (errors / logs / description / expected outcome), show some form of attempt to solve the issue or at the least, the research that they tried looking for a solution and that are coherent.** ***So, those that follow the [tour].***

Comment: '*I barely see any upvotes at all*' - No kidding, if you take a look at most of the questions (not all) that are asked, they generally don't help us help them by including the relevant information and in many instances, they don't even include *their* code.

Comment: I've mentioned in the description: "I see that many of the question are asked by new users who ask terrible question often, that's why they get downvotes". So I know about those questions. But some are pretty good ones, yet get downvotes or no upvotes

Comment: What do you define as "good"? Could you share some examples of *good down-voted* questions?

Comment: While this post could be _argued_ as opinion based, there are a lot of guidelines on how to use votes, and they're segmented out a bit. I see value in this question, honestly. At least the OP wants to understand how they should use their votes, rather than "Ah! This post was downvoted! That's totally unfair, I'mma upvote to cancel that!" The OP here shows more thought than that, and we should encourage and educate users who show such thought and care to our system and site.

Comment: I upvote questions that are clear, well-presented, show personal effort to solve the problem roger asking, including all the obvious legwork like googling and reading the the relevant documentation, or are interesting, or a useful combination of any of those attributes. I downvote the obese that are unclear, don’t contain sufficient information (which would be obvious to a reasonable person to have included) to answer, and particularly of they no show no effort on the behalf of the laser before asking strangers on the internet to donate their time and expertise to help.

Comment: @Kendra my reasoning behind my comment was that I assumed the OP could've dome what you did, that is, piece the information together from the [tour] / [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: [still plenty of up-votes](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/813466/up-accept-and-down-votes-over-time#graph). Maybe in 6 to 8 years the numbers are closer, finally.

Comment: @script47 I could see them finding parts of what I pieced together, but some of those pages aren't incredibly obvious and easy to find. The tooltips aren't exactly obvious, and a newer user might not find/think of the privilege pages right away. Summing it all up in one place, along with the unwritten rule of _"Really, it's up to you"_ and the two _major_ rules... Not a bad idea, in my opinion.

Comment: I cannot remember.

Answer (score 16):

Well, let's look at the guidelines.

Start by reading the tooltip on the upvote arrow:

> This question shows research effort; it is clear and useful.

That's a good starting point.

Now, check out the tooltip for the downvote arrow:

> This question does not show research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

Alright, that gives us three criteria to look at right off the bat: Research effort, clarity, and usefulness.

Cool. What else can we use to clarify these guidelines?

How about the privilege page for upvotes?

> #### When should I vote up?
>
> Whenever you encounter a question, answer or comment that you feel is especially useful, vote it up!
>
> You have a limited number of votes per day, so use them wisely.

Alright, we've narrowed down the "useful" guideline to "especially useful." Cool again.

So, what about the downvotes privilege page?

> #### When should I vote down?
>
> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an
> egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is
> clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.
>
> You have a limited number of votes per day, and answer down-votes cost
> you a tiny bit of reputation on top of that; use them wisely.

So, sloppy no-effort posts are bad. Incorrect posts should not be upvoted. Alright... What else?

What about the "Why is voting important?" help page? The first line of the last paragraph is very relevant:

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate information.

---

Well, that's all useful information! But... It doesn't really give you a solid "Always upvote this, always downvote that" answer, does it?

That's where the last guideline comes in: Vote as you feel is appropriate.

Do *you* think a post is worthy of an upvote? Well, then upvote it. Your votes help us see the aggregate community value of posts.

All of the above count as *guidelines* and not hard, fast rules. You'll only encounter two rules for voting anywhere on our sites:

Do not use extra accounts (also known as "sock puppets") to vote in ways you could not with one account. For example, voting twice on one post or voting for your own posts.

Do not target your votes to users. For example, don't upvote a post just because your friend made it, and don't upvote a post just because the poster gave a good answer elsewhere. If you vote organically and without searching out users to vote on, you should *never* run afoul of this rule.

As a final note, keep in mind that just because a post looks clear and useful doesn't always mean it's on-topic for our site or completely up to our high standards. Does it have an MCVE? (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example) Does it give any errors thrown? Is all the code *in* the question, not hidden behind a link? That sort of thing.

When in doubt about the quality of a question per our standards, there is no shame in revisiting the [help center](//stackoverflow.com/help) to double check what we expect of posts. I still do so on a regular basis, and I'm sure other frequent users do as well.